# How to group rows in Latex?

Tags: tables

I want a row grouping like [this table](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html). Is it possible to do so in Latex? In the following table, city name is the attribute that is used to group rows.

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! and why you not use code which is there?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Would you mind giving us a sample table to start from?  @Zarko I don't understand what you mean.  The code that is there is html/js/css, not tex.

Comment: ups, i didn't look carefully enough. looks for questions with tag `colortbl` or `xcolor`. here is tons such a questions and answers :-). at least provide minimal working example -- a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending by `\end{document}` -- with your table. then will be easy to add row coloring.

Comment: @Zarko Because I could not use the code in Latex:), btw I uploaded a minimal sample.

Comment: @Teepeemm I've uploaded a sample image, could you please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: Would you mind giving us *the tex code for* a sample table to start with.  It's a bit more work on your end, but it saves everyone else a lot of time.  And making your own table can be instructive as well.

Comment: @Teepeemm is the uploaded code useful?

Comment: The code snippet seems to have no discernible connection to the screenshot you posted. Please clarify how either the screenshot or the code (or both) should be interpreted.

Comment: @Mico screenshot is a sample to convey the meaning of row grouping, the code is the one that I am working on and in the screenshot the column is city but I do not have city column instead I have Category column which I want to use as my grouping column

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying ro achieve: first  you mention `row grouping`, but finally you ask for `column grouping`. Could you explain more precisely what this mean?

Comment: @Bernard Row grouping should be done by a column

Comment: Always not very clear. Do  you something like merging cells in a row, or merging cells in a column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `xcolor` package with the `table` option, you can use `\rowcolors` for colouring  normal  rows and `\rowcolor` (singular) for rows used as headers, as in this example:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}\hline
\rowcolor{gray!50}\multicolumn{2}{c}{Endinburg}\\
aaa & bbb \\
aaa & bbb \\
aaa & bbb \\
\rowcolor{gray!50}\multicolumn{2}{c}{London}\\
aaa & bbb \\
aaa & bbb \\
aaa & bbb \\
\hline  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```